# Visual Studio 2022 "Add Service Reference" uses Newtonsoft Json.NET instead of System.Text.Json

Tags: json, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I have a ASP.NET 6 Web API, using System.Text.Json for Json serialization.

If I use the feature "Add Service Reference" of Visual Studio 2022, the C# generated code still uses Newtonson Json.NET library for Json serialization.

[image]

As a result, some API calls fail complaining about wrong serialization.

Is there a way to have Visual Studio generate code that uses Sysem.Text.Json instead of Newtonsoft?

Comment: `Add Service Reference` to what? That's typically used for SOAP, ie XML, web services. OpenAPI and gRPC are later addition that first appeared in the `Connected Services`, not `Service Reference` dialog. I suspect you mean `OpenAPI` ?

Comment: Even [last year's VS blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/generating-http-api-clients-using-visual-studio-connected-services/) showed the OpenAPI reference in `Connected Services`. It's not VS itself that generates the proxy either. VS doesn't deal with Swagger/OpenAPI itself, it uses either Swashbuckle or NSwag. The blog post shows a call to `dotnet swagger`. In VS 2022, `Service Reference` adds an [OpenApiReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/microsoft.dotnet-openapi?view=aspnetcore-6.0) tag with `CodeGenerator="NSwagCSharp"`.

Comment: What problems do you have right now? Perhaps it's easier to fix these than use STJ, perhaps not. [NSwag only offers experimental support](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2243) for System.Text.Json and no way to configure this through the `OpenApiReference` tag that I could find. Even if there is, you probably don't want to use a half-finished code generator. If you want to use STJ you may want to use one of the other NSwag generators like NSwagStudio to generate the classes explicitly and fix any problems

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos One problem I have is with strings. If an API call returns simply a string I get an exception in the generated code "Couldn't deserialize as string".

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I tried the experimental support for STJ, but it doesn't work. I checked the generated code and imho it doesn't operate always properly. For example, if I have a method that just returns a string, the response content is correct but the generated code still tries to deserialize it, which fails of course as it is not json but plain text